# How to use hugo-leaflet library or just using leaflet in an Hugo template

Tags: leaflet, hugo

I try to use the library [hugo-leaflet](https://github.com/altrdev/hugo-leaflet) but I wasn't able to move forward the first explications.

- Font Awesome icons is in my project,
- I downloaded the zip, placed the shortcodes files in theme>layouts>shortcodes,
- the  JS files in theme>assets>js,
- the images in my-project>assets>images
- and the min.css file in my-project>public>css
- I added `{{ partial "leaflet-loader" . }}` in the html page of my project i wanted to work on
- and in my `<head> {{ if .HasShortcode "leaflet-map" }} {{ partial "leaflet-loader" . }} {{ end }}`

but when I pasted `{{< leaflet-map mapHeight="500px" mapWidth="100%" mapLat="27.66995" mapLon="85.43249" >}}` in my .md content file I have this error in my console: `failed to unmarshal YAML: yaml: line 7: could not find expected ':'`

I guess I'm doing something wrong but I can't find what. It's the first time I use Hugo and Leaflet and now I'm quite lost. What can I try next?

I try to use leaflet without the library but I wasn't able to use customIcon and clusterMarker.

Comment: You could start with sharing your code.